# SP13: Linking to Network Drive on Team Site

Tags: 2013, javascript, document-library, jquery, network-drive

Normally, I can add a link that points to my network drive from my team home site quick launch with no issue.  Not now. I add a the link to my network drive to a folder and will not open.  I know the link is right.  I am using Edge that does not work but is my default browser.  It works in IE but this browser is not my default.  I thought about adding all documents into sharepoint library but there are tooooo many documents and folders.

My question is there a way to connect to my network drive in sharepoint without using a direct link as I normally do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft Edge does not support the `file://` protocol, which is why it doesn't work. You'll have to use another browser to meet your requirement. And no, a direct link using the `file://` protocol is the only thing you can do.